# Embarrassingly parallel example

Tags: parallel-processing

I am totally new to the world of parallel programming. I intend to know that if there is a java program called Task A, which contains 10 sub tasks T1...T10, where T1 reads data from table A1,  T2 from table A2...T10 from table A10, using the same key say employee_id, is the problem called embarrassingly parallel ? I was thinking of employing 10 threads to do each of the sub tasks.

Comment: @Rndm:- Is this problem "embarrassingly parallel" ?

Comment: Embarrassingly parallel problems are such where the execution of each subtask does not depend on the execution of the other subtasks, i.e. there is no inter-task data dependence. If reading from table `Ai` (with `i` varying from 1 to 10) does not lock resources used by other reads, then yes, this is an embarrassingly parallel problem.